# Pyinstaller to create linux binary getting Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe8' error

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, build, pyinstaller

I am trying to create linux binary file using pyinstaller tool using below command.

```
  # pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Before converting binary file main.py is running fine.

After converting to binary file i am getting below error when i try to run a script.

```
 File "main", line 1
 SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe8' in file main on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Enviroment:

```
  Python script version: 3.6
  pyinstaller version: 3.5
  OS using for pyinstaller create: Linux (Redhat)
  script running OS: linux (Redhat)
```

Anything i required to consider for Linux OS for pyinstaller tool and how i do i fix the issue

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show a hex dump around the problematic byte? See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: How exactly are you running `main`?

Comment: i am running binary like python3.6 main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the Python interpreter to run a binary. Just run `./main` directly.

Comment: is it possible to tell pyinstaller build with python3.6 version